# show that $(1+ \frac {x}{n})^n < e^x$ and $e^x < (1- \frac{x}{n})^{-n}$ if $x<n$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

If $n$ is a positive integer and if $x>0$,show that

$(1+ \frac {x}{n})^n < e^x \quad$   and that   $\quad e^x < (1- \frac{x}{n})^{-n} \quad $ if $x<n$

I proved the first one by the inequalities 
$$(1+ \frac{x}{n})^n = \sum^{n}_{k=0} \binom{n}{k} \frac{x^k}{n^k} \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!} <e^x$$

the second one is equal to $(1- \frac{x}{n})^n <e^{-x}$ but I feel I couldn't find a way to start.

In a previous exercise I proved
 $$(-1)^n e^{-x} < (-1)^n \sum^{n}_{k=0}(-1)^k \frac{x^k}{k!}$$ 
it  seems to have some relation with the second question.So I hope someone could give me a hint.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you defining $e^x$ in the first place?

Comment: I learned calculus by apostol's book.And he define $e^x$ as the inverse function of logarithm.

Comment: And the logarithm is defined as? The point is that there are several ways in which these functions can be first defined. How you prove things depends on the definition you started with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By convexity (or by any of a number of other approaches, for example because $\log(1+x)\leqslant x$ for every $x\gt-1$), the graph of the exponential is above its tangent at $0$, that is,

> $\color{red}{\text{For every real number}\ x,}$
>   $$\color{red}{1+x\leqslant\mathrm e^x.}$$

Apply this to $x/n$ and raise to the power $n$, this yields the first inequality.

Apply this to $-x/n$ and raise to the power $n$, this yields $(1-x/n)^n\leqslant\mathrm e^{-x}$ hence, composing by $u\mapsto1/u$, the second inequality.

Comment: As so often before, $e^x\ge 1+x$ turns out to be the most important inequality about the exonential

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yep. Your comment convinced me to add some color...